# Can anyone help me convert this ANTLR 2.0 grammar file to ANTLR 3.0 syntax?

Tags: parsing, antlr, rdf

I've converted the 'easy' parts (fragment,  @header and @member
declerations etc.), but since I'm new to Antlr I have  a really hard
time converting the Tree statements etc.

I use the following [migration guide](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Migrating+from+ANTLR+2+to+ANTLR+3#MigratingfromANTLR2toANTLR3-NewinANTLR3).

[The grammar file can be found here.](http://jena.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/jena/jena2/src/com/)...

Below you can find some examples where I run into problems:

For instance, I have problems with:

```
n3Directive0!:
                d:AT_PREFIX ns:nsprefix u:uriref
                {directive(#d, #ns, #u);}
                ;
```

or

```
propertyList![AST subj]
        : NAME_OP! anonnode[subj] propertyList[subj]
        | propValue[subj] (SEMI propertyList[subj])?
        |               // void : allows for [ :a :b ] and empty list "; .".
        ;

propValue [AST subj]
        :  v1:verb objectList[subj, #v1]
                // Reverse the subject and object
        |  v2:verbReverse subjectList[subj, #v2]
        ;

subjectList![AST oldSub, AST prop]
        : obj:item { emitQuad(#obj, prop, oldSub) ; }
                (COMMA subjectList[oldSub, prop])? ;

objectList! [AST subj, AST prop]
        : obj:item { emitQuad(subj,prop,#obj) ; }
                (COMMA objectList[subj, prop])?
    | // Allows for empty list ", ."
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n3Directive0!:
                d=AT_PREFIX ns=nsprefix u=uriref
                {directive($d, $ns, $u);}
                ;
```

- You have to use '=' for  assignments.
- Tokens can then be used as '$tokenname.getText()', ...
- Rule results can then be used in your  code as 'rulename.result'
- If you have  rules having declared result names, you have to use these names iso.
  'result'.